# autocomplete arrow keys not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

im using autocomplete to retrieve data from the database

```
$('input[name=\'product_name\']').autocomplete({

  'source': function(request, response) {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/autocomplete&name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request), //Controller route
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        response($.map(json, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item['name'],
            value: item['product_id']
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },

  'select': function(item) {

    $('input[name=\'product_id\']').val(item['value']);
    $('input[name=\'product_name\']').val(item['label']);
  },

    focus: function(event, ui) {
          return false;
    }
});
```

i already put the focus return false but my dropdown arrow keys still not working.
i also tried using event.preventDefault();

Comment: probably irrelevant/small.. but shouldn't `'source':` and `'select':` not have the apostrophes around them? I.e. it should be `source:` and `select:` Unless that's just how it formatted when you posted. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: already tried that sir but still not working

Comment: @mmcrae it doesn't matter in a JavaScript object... But it sure looks ugly ;)

Comment: The arrow keys are working fine https://jsfiddle.net/q0pL4j0o/. Please create an [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score -1):

There is some problem with your `select` event handler of `jquery-ui-autocomplete`. So try this script -

```
$('input[name=\'product_name\']').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/autocomplete&name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request), //Controller route
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        response($.map(json, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item['name'],
            value: item['product_id']
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event , ui) {
    $('input[name=\'product_id\']').val(ui.item.value);
    $('input[name=\'product_name\']').val(ui.item.lable);
  },
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

> `jquery-ui-autocomplete` event **select** callback specified:
>
> *$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ select: function( event, ui ) {} });*

And hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: arrow keys are working fine with his code... Please don't post answers without even understanding the problem

Comment: @TJ, the issue in code was with select event and not able to set value on select item of autocomplete as I'd checked the code.

Comment: That's not the issue mentioned in the questions title or description by the OP. This doesn't answer the question.